# attribute related to attribute in other table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to update the `NULL` values with new value from the last known value based on `ID` & `DATE` columns. Note that, The non-null value update should change whenever `ID` column is changing.

The below example query, `Null` is replaced by 5 in L2 & 01-12-2016 row but it should be null as `ID` is changed to L2 and 5 is bringing from L1 row. But I need to get `R_ID` from whenever `ID` is changing.

My table has 90 million rows, and update process should be fast as much as possible.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
     ID nvarchar(10), 
     DATE date,
     R_ID INT
);

INSERT INTO #temp
    SELECT 'L1', '2016-12-01', NULL 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'L1', '2016-12-02', 5 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'L1', '2016-12-03', NULL 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'L2', '2016-12-01', NULL 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'L2', '2016-12-02', 8 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'L2', '2016-12-03', NULL
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'L3', '2016-12-03', 3 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'L3', '2016-12-04', NULL 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'L3', '2016-12-04', NULL ;

DECLARE @R_ID INT;

UPDATE #temp WITH(TABLOCKX)
SET @R_ID = R_ID = CASE WHEN R_ID IS NULL THEN @R_ID ELSE R_ID END
OPTION(MAXDOP 1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use in inner query for the update statement:

```
UPDATE t1
SET R_ID = ISNULL(R_ID, (
                        SELECT TOP 1 R_ID 
                        FROM #Temp t2 
                        WHERE t2.ID = t1.Id 
                        AND T2.[DATE] < t1.[DATE] 
                        AND t2.R_ID IS NOT NULL 
                        ORDER BY [DATE] DESC)
                 )
FROM #Temp t1
```

Test update:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Temp
```

Results:

```
ID  DATE                    R_ID
L1  01.12.2016 00:00:00     NULL
L1  02.12.2016 00:00:00     5
L1  03.12.2016 00:00:00     5
L2  01.12.2016 00:00:00     NULL
L2  02.12.2016 00:00:00     8
L2  03.12.2016 00:00:00     8
L3  03.12.2016 00:00:00     3
L3  04.12.2016 00:00:00     3
L3  04.12.2016 00:00:00     3
```

Comment: The logic is working but query is taking more than a hour to update 90 m records.

Comment: Well if, 90 m refers to 90,000,000 records then it's not that long for an update with a sub query...